# If someone is inflight with a flow and a new version of the flow is activated, can there be related errors?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a highly used flow by multiple users and I want to make a business hours change to the flow.

If someone is using a flow and a new version of the flow is activated before they finish their interaction, will an error be returned during the switch to a new page or will the interaction finish in the version of the flow they started with?

In my particular use case, I am modifying a field with a value that no other aspect of the flow or other functionality is dependent on.

I am unable to find any documentation related to how this would impact users currently in a flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a flow starts, that version will be used throughout the entire flow process. This means that users using the flow before you make the new version active will continue to use the old version for the rest of the flow process. Flows started after the new version is activated will use the new version.